# "Unterminated string literal" error when calling JS function in Smarty

Tags: javascript, smarty

I'm getting this error when I try to call a Javascript function from a Smarty page. I know what the error is about generally - but I don't understand why it happens in this case.

The function which throws the error is called in the following manner:

```
<a href='#' onClick="showActualSize({$id_product},'{$realsize|escape:'htmlall'}');">Actual Size</a>
```

In this case, the variables have the following values;

$id_product = 544;
$realsize = "Imperial: LR14 Metric: MN1400";

I used `escape:'htmlall'` to escape any special chars that may appear in `$realsize` but, as you see, there aren't any in this example.

However, when I look at the page source code, there appear to be new lines in the `$realsize` variable, as the source looks like this:

```
<li><a href='#' onClick="showActualSize(544,'Imperial: LR14
Metric: MN1400
');">Actual Size</a></li>
```

Am I looking at some hidden characters that are causing the error? How can I get around this?

Comment: Escape it as JavaScript, not html, because you're emitting it in JavaScript, not html.

Comment: @DaveNewton - He actually needs to use *both* escapes, in sequence.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm very new to Smarty even though I have lots of PHP experience.

Comment: That'd depend in what the function does, wouldn't it? It only needs to be html-escaped if it shows up in html, which isn't clear.

Comment: Never mind, using `{$realsize|escape:'htmlall'|escape:javascript}` fixed the issue. I used html escape because the string could contain quotes etc.

Comment: @robert Probably now you could "Answer Your Question" and close that question as resolved. Because its difficult to figure out whether you solved problem or not by reading jsut a comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `{$realsize|escape:'htmlall'|escape:javascript}` has fixed the issue by removing the new line characters which were causing it.